# How to reduce multilevel of braces in text

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I am looking for help about text containing multilevel of braces

For example with this text :

```
{{abc|{cde|fgh}} bb|cc}
```

I want to obtain

```
{abc bb|cde bb|fgh bb|cc}
```

and with this

```
pp {vv {ff|ii|nn|aa} | {ee|hh|rr} } xx {{abc|{cde|fgh} bb|cc}
```

the results is

```
pp {vv ff|vv ii|vv nn|vv aa | ee|hh|rr} xx {abc bb|cde bb|fgh bb|cc}
```

the idea is to put the text with several levels of braces only one level of braces.

How can I do that?
I want to do this in C#.

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Want to show us what you've tried?

Comment: No I have not tried because I do not know how do that. I have no idea of the algorithm to be implemented.

Comment: input process output -> parse text into tree, canonicalize tree, render text from tree. Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: @Kris Vandermotten parse text into tree and canonicalize tree

Answer (score 1):

I'll just give you the basic idea, as opposed to writing the code for you.

Build a tree (well, sort of a tree) of every part of the string inside the outer-most `{}`'s (`a {b} c {d}` would have 2 trees - one for `{b}` and one for `{d}`). Each element following on another must be a child of that element. Whenever there are multiple options, each of them must be a child of the previous node and each of them must have the next node as a child.

So for, for example, `{a {b|c} d e | f}`, you'd have:

```
         -> b -
        /      \
  -> a -        -> d -> e
 /      \      /
/        -> c -
\
 \
  -> f
```

Then generate all paths from the root, using [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for example.

The paths are `-> a -> b -> d -> e` and `-> a -> c -> d -> e` and `-> f`,
so we'd have `{a b d e | a c d e | f}`.

**Implementation hints:**

A [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) might be a good idea for keeping track of the nodes.

It might be wise to have blank intermediate nodes before and after `{}`'s (trust me, this would make it a lot easier to implement).

So `{{a|b} {c|d}}` would look like:

```
       -> a -        -> c -
      /      \      /      \
-> . -        -> . -        -> .
      \      /      \      /
       -> b -        -> d -
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Another implementation is to use [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) with and  applying a [depth-first-search algorithm](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Depth%20First%20Search%20Example) on a graph.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to find the vertices (a, b, c, ...) because I do not know the use of parsers.

Comment: @PapyRef `{`, `|` and `}` should be the only characters you need to look out for. Whatever's between any of those can basically be taken as a vertex. Take a few (trivial and non-trivial) examples and create the trees by hand. Then try to define explicit steps for what you need to do and each of those 3 characters (keeping in mind that the stack is all-important here).

Answer (score 1):

Lexer rules (I use [NLT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/) format):

```
"|" -> PIPE;
/[a-z]+/ -> ID;
/[ ]+/ -> WS;
"{" -> LBRACE;
"}" -> RBRACE;
%EOF -> EOF;
```

And parser:

```
s -> n:node { n };
node -> (PIPE- n:node)+ { new SeqNode("|",n) }
      | (WS- n:node)+ { new SeqNode(" ",a) }
      | LBRACE n:node RBRACE { new BracesNode(seq) }
      | id:ID { new SeqNode("",new string[]{id}) }
      ;
```

*I am writing  this off the top of my head ;-).*

Define `SeqNode` and `BracesNode` to get a tree. Next traverse it, and count how many times you hit BracesNode -- when the counter says "the first time", recreate braces, if more -- ignore them.

Comment: Very interesting tool. But I found little documentation for beginners for NaiveLanguageTools format and C# example code (I only find some code in  Example project).

Comment: @PapyRef There is a documentation about syntax in generator project, and I wrote this piece 2 days ago: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/679139/Ambiguity-Let-NLT-parse-it-for-you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a non-regular expression grammar parser in order to parse the text to a sequence of tokens. See [How to write a Parser in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377344/how-do-i-write-a-parser-in-c) for advice on writing such parsers.

Compared with that, reformatting the tokens (probably via a binary expression tree) should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If there are oprators right outside braces that has higher precedence than the lowest of those of oprators inside, you keep the braces,otherwise you drop them