# Recognize part of text, then handle like function?

Tags: c#, function, parsing, methods, compiler-construction

I am currently working on a basic Ti-basic compiler, made in C#

It recognizes basic commands like ":Pause" and ":Output", but I would like it to recognize

```
:Output(1,1, "good ol' ti-basic"
```

Is it possible to recognize text, then treat it like a function e.g. (int y, int x, string text) ?

So Let's say I have the following string:

```
string str1 = :Output(1,1, "good ol' ti-basic"
```

How would I recognize the "Output" part, then divide it in the 3 parts int x, int y and string text?

Something like

```
// if(str1.contains"Output")
{
  // divide into int x, int y and string text
  // then Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
  // Console.Write(text);
}
```

Is the above possible?

Comment: Writing the parser of the Ti-basic language (or any other language) is not a trivial task. What is exactly that you are asking? How you could parse arguments given to a function?

Comment: If I understand the questions correctly, you want to write a custom parser for the given language. Can you look through the links in this question and see if they help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377344/how-do-i-write-a-parser-in-c

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry but I did not know that word, "parser", thus making it very hard to find anything about what I wanted. This is pretty much the answer..