# Parsing a user submitted search query

Tags: c#, linq, search

In my web app, I want to allow my user to search for specific articles.

I need to support the following operators:

```
AND
OR
NOT
( )
" "
```

A search query could be something like:

```
aaa AND bbb AND (ccc or ddd) NOT "eee fff"
```

If possible, wildcards like `*` and `?` should be supported too.

If possible, I would love to end up with a Linq expression, that will allow me to query EF, ElasticLINQ or Linq2SQL.

Do you know of any projects that allow me to accomplish this in a somewhat easy way?

I have been looking at Irony and Antlr, but they seem like overkill for this.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
If you have any suggestions as to how I could program this myself, I would be very interested too. But someone must have been in this position before.

Comment: Do the user have to write `AND`, `OR`, ...? Are they programmers? Are you not overengineering a little? You realize you would also need to do some syntax check(`AND AND AND AND(OR OR OR) NOT NOT NOT`) Dont see any _simple_ solution for this. If you really need to make such search functionality try to make it without the need for user to WRITE anything(especially if he is not a programmer) Make him click, select, drag, drop, but NOT write search queries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The person entering the query is the administrator of the website and is familiar with the syntax.

Comment: I agree that this is almost certainly over-engineering.  Is the purpose of this to find articles using syntax that the advanced find does not support, or are you trying to give a non-CRM user access to the articles?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently implemented a similar parser myself, and it was rather tough task. I had to define the grammar, implement lexical and syntactic analysis, and also expression evaluation logic. Here it is: [see Vb.Net code on Gist](https://gist.github.com/GusRustam/9e766fcf5ac7894c2a10).

I do not provide much details here, as, IMHO, it is not the best way to go for you, unless you have experience of writing such code.

At the same time, I never heard of any tools that allowed to automate such syntactic and lexical analysis and were easy to use.

I know there were [Lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29), [Yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) and [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), but these all are for C++ and they are imho quite complex. Never found anything interesting for C#.

Hence, I would suggest you to consider it once again, whether you really need to implement it this way.

**UPD**: I found a nice SO question which could be useful for you, should you try to implement your own parser: [How to write a Parser in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377344/how-do-i-write-a-parser-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:

1. **use your own DSL** (take a look @ http://www.antlr.org/)
2. **call a odata web service / wcf data service** to use standarized queries
   see example @ http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is handle this the way Microsoft Dynamics CRM handles this in their advanced find: instead of having the user enter their own search string manually, they have a graphical UI which gets turned into the proper string when you search for it.

[image]

I see that you are making this for someone familiar with the syntax. Even if the person knows how the query works, I still would go for this method:

1. It's far easier to determine how a query works from a visual representation than from a text.
2. It's easier to work with, even if you have experience with the syntax.
3. Syntax Errors are harder to make, because the syntax is automatically generated.